# PHP Creating a credit memo from invoice number

Tags: orders, creditmemo

Currently I am using the code below to refund a full order and create the creditmemo..

```
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100091904');
        $invoices = array();
        foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $invoice) {
            if ($invoice->canRefund()) {
                $invoices[] = $invoice;
            }
        }

        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order);
        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            $creditmemo = $service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo($invoice);
            $creditmemo->refund();
        }
```

But the problem is that the customer paid online with SagePay, this current method ONLY refunds this offline and as you can see this could be a very big problem, anyone got any ways to get around this? Would be much appreciated. Using Magento Enterprise ver. 1.12.0.2

I've not found anything on this before this purely REFUNDING online.

Comment: If the extension provider didn't implement it, it is either not possible or it is not yet done. Ask the extention provider.

Comment: It works doing it manually in Magento, but if I refund the full order it goes offline, I have to go to refund individually each invoice, thus why I thought this would work.

Comment: Ah ok, yes then you make something wrong... Don'T ask me what :D

Comment: Yup ha, just wondering where.. Any Idea? damn.. ha

Comment: Will create it offline because its converting the order into a credit memo, which creates offline order even on Magento.. Don't see why they would want to do that... I found this but [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936631/magento-create-credit-memo-refund-programmatically-through-code) the link to the API is dud.

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow your last comment.

The question I referenced had this answer, [there is more](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5569/programmatically-create-a-credit-memo):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('1117575');
$orderItem = $order->getItemsCollection()->getItemByColumnValue('sku', '100-0055-BRO-S');
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order);
$data = array(
    'qtys' => array(
        $orderItem->getId() => 1
    )
);
$creditMemo = $service->prepareCreditmemo($data)->save();
```

Comment: This will just create an offline refund on the Order, I believe it needs to be done on the Invoice.

Comment: Try `$service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo()`

Comment: Thats what I'm using currently, unsure why it wouldn't work. Surely more people have this problem.