# Cancelling of orders by customer

Tags: magento-1.8, orders

I want to allow customers should have option in front-end to **cancel** orders. My doubt is when a customer can cancel an order ?

1. Can an order which is invoiced be cancelled by a customer ?
2. Can an order which is shipped be cancelled by a customer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an order is invoiced it can no longer be canceled. The only way to 'undo' that order is to create a Credit memo.

When an order is shipping it's put on complete and as far as Magento is concerned the whole order is already handled. A credit memo can still be made though if an invoice exists.

There is a [Mage SO post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5594/50) on creating credit memo's programmatically you can use to build a feature that would allow for a customer to 'cancel' his order.

On a side note tho, having a customer canceling or crediting an order might have negative effects such as refunds not be processed. You might be better off building a contact form in the customer account section where the user can pick one of his orders and send a cancellation request. Inchoo has [an article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/) on building forms with email functionality.

Answer (score 0):

**Cancel**

> Cancels all items that have not been invoiced and/or shipped. If some
>   of the quantity of a line item has already been invoiced and/or
>   shipped, only the remaining quantity will be canceled, and this amount
>   will display in the quantity column as Qty Canceled. The item status
>   will remain either shipped or invoiced. If none of the quantity for
>   the line item has been invoiced and/or shipped, all of the quantity
>   will be canceled, and the item status will become canceled. Any time
>   an order is canceled, a notification should automatically be sent to
>   the customer in the format of the order confirmation email. It should
>   also display the status of each line item and the qty ordered,
>   invoiced, shipped, refunded, and canceled.

For more information please refer [**this**](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/welcome_to_the_magento_user_s_guide/chapter_8) Url.

Comment: I got the information from Sander Mangel's answer, but your answer is also informative. I don't have the reputation to up vote.