# Programmatically update the quantity of an item ordered in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have to edit the quantity of some items programmatically in Magento.

Say a customer ordered for 5 kg of Apples and 10 qantity of pens. But then he rejects 1 kg of apple and 5 pens because of say poor quality or whatsoever the reason. So i need to update them in my credit memo and the price should also automatically update accordingly along with taxes and everything so that customer has to pay for 4 kg of apples and 5 pens only. How to apply this functionality to magento programmatically?

I am using magento 1.9.2.3 version.

Please help me. I am a novice in magento and I am stuck at this point. Thankyou in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Refund (I mean `Creditmemo`) of returned items. This will automatically deduct QTY(ies) from Order/Invoice.

For that Go to admin Order grid > View Order. Now click `Credit Memo` button (if it's not there, that means Invoice is not generated yet).

In this Page, you can see all the Items Ordered/Invoiced. You can deduct the QTYs from `Qty to Refund` column and click on `Update Qty's`, this will show the Totals (Refund Totals).

In `Refund Totals` block, **`Adjustment Refund`** and **`Adjustment Fee`** are important fields also known as `Positive Adjustment` and `Negative Adjustment` respectively.
Amounts entered in `Adjustment Refund` will be added to the totals and `Adjustment Fee` will be substracted from totals. So you can adjust CUSTOM Totals from these fields.

Comment: How to achieve this functionality through a code?

Comment: I have explained the DEFAULT magento functionality. What to build here ?

Comment: As you told Go to admin Order grid > View Order and then click on Credit Memo. Instead of doing that I want to write a code for that so that the updated order stores in the database automatically by calling some type of rest api without manually going and creating the credit memo.

Comment: check here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5569/programmatically-create-a-credit-memo